# Problem with searchbar in Django and HTML

Tags: html, django, searchbar

I have created a searchbar in Django and HTML, however, this gives me problems.
If I enter "Apple iPhone 13 Pro" in the searchbar it will not find any results, because the URL is not encode. The URL is: Apple+iPhone+13+Pro, but it should be: Apple+iPhone%C2%A0%.
How can I solve?

Comment: can you share your view and urls.py file?

Answer (score 0):

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
 path('search', Search.as_view(), name='search_fields')
]
```

views.py

```
class Search(ListView):
 template_name = 'blog.html'
 paginate_by = 10
 
 def get_queryset(self):
  query = self.request.GET.get('ricerca')
  object_list = Post.objects.filter(Q(titolo_post=query)).order_by('-data')
  return object_list
```

views.py

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you don't get the result is not this. Are you sure that your object filtering is working? And be sure that what you get with `GET.get()` by printing it out.

```
class Search(ListView):
 template_name = 'blog.html'
 paginate_by = 10
 
 def get_queryset(self):
  query = self.request.GET.get('ricerca')
  print(query,"*"*20)
  object_list = Post.objects.filter(Q(titolo_post__icontains=query)).order_by('-data')
  return object_list
```

Comment: Where is the print printed?

Comment: @programming on the command line

Comment: "GET /static/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1830 "https://tecnhd.herokuapp.com/search?csrfmiddlewaretoken=QMEZOPDgY1YMGt1DbdDTzpVOJoXzGRdK1rqtYbKuicMJYZpe7tE5vnz3SvMsE3Jq&ricerca=Apple+iPhone+13+Pro+Max"

Comment: "GET /static/js/base.js HTTP/1.1" 200 639 "https://tecnhd.herokuapp.com/search?csrfmiddlewaretoken=QMEZOPDgY1YMGt1DbdDTzpVOJoXzGRdK1rqtYbKuicMJYZpe7tE5vnz3SvMsE3Jq&ricerca=Apple+iPhone+13+Pro+Max"

Comment: This is the url I get by looking in the search bar for "iPhone 13 Pro Max", but to make it work, there must be %C2%A0 before the number 13, so you get the URL: Apple+iPhone%C2%A013+Pro+Max

Comment: Give me permission for this project on GitHub. I will send you a pull request

Comment: Could you help me without logging into my project?

Comment: To better understand my problem, visit my site (https://tecnhd.herokuapp.com/) and search for "Apple iPhone". After seeing the results search for "Apple iPhone 13 Pro".
If you notice in the second case it doesn't find results because in the URL before 13 there is a +.

Answer (score 0):

The result I get it if I enter like: "Samsung S22 Ultra".
However, if I put "Apple iPhone 13 Pro" as there is a number, it will not find any results, because the URL should be: "Apple + iPhone%C2%A013 + Pro".

Comment: Can you let me know what result you get by print(query,"*"*20)?

And delete these answers you should explain them in comments